# XML editor Intellij - can't find any

Tags: xml, eclipse, user-interface, intellij-idea, editor

Does Intellij Idea Ultimate have something like Eclipse does - XML editor? I searched for plugins and I found nothing. It's paid software after all - it should have something better then none paid one...

Answer (score 0):

No need for a plugin, xml support is included in the application. It's also included in the free and open source IntelliJ IDEA Community edition by the way.